# req.body an empty object when using a static file but has content when using postman

Tags: node.js, forms, google-chrome, express

I have an express API that sends a static html file that it self has a script tag with a fetch request. That request goes to the same API but a different route. When I do the request with postman the body has content but not when I do it through chrome. So I'm curious what postman is doing differently?

Ive changed the content-type headers as well as having messed around with the form's enctype and a bunch of additional things.

It's easier to just link the github project : https://github.com/dshrops1/helio-teams

the static file I serve is under servers/authen/expressfiles

Any help or resources would be appreicated.

edit: `{ 'object Object': '' }` is what is in the body when done from the browser , when done from postman I get the actual body `{ user: "blalba" , pass: "blala"}` or something along those lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so Im not sure why I could not send json like I have done with my other forms using the right Content-type and JSON.Stringify(), but for some reason on my express server it would give me an empty object.

So the solution was making sure my form was using x-www-form-urlencoded and then figuring out how to send data in the body with that type of form data and it required me to send a template string such as:

```
fetch("/urlfetchingfrom", {
  method: "POST",
  ....
  body: `id1=${value}&id2=${value2}`
  })
```

doing this allowed me to gain access to the data on my server.

Comment: So it actually came down to being a CORS issue that I just did not understand well enough and I'm back to using application/json  but there server is using CORS